# Passing list of YAML properties from Docker compose to Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker-compose

My spring Boot application contains the following list of properties in `application.yml`:

```json
hs:
  targets:
    - name: system_a
      url: https://system-a
      username: username-a
      password: password-a
    - name: system_b
      url: https://system-b
      username: username-b
      password: password-b
```

Instead of defining them there, I'd like to pass them from Docker Compose via `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
my-app:
  image: my-image
  ports:
    - 9002:9002
  environment:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
    HS_TARGETS_NAME: system-a
    HS_TARGETS_URL: https://system-a
    HS_TARGETS_USERNAME: username_a
    HS_TARGETS_PASSWORD: password_a
    HS_TARGETS_NAME: system-b
    HS_TARGETS_URL: https://system-b
    HS_TARGETS_USERNAME: username_b
    HS_TARGETS_PASSWORD: password_b
```

But I doubt that this will work because the variables all have the same name. Is there any way to do that or do I have to restructore my Spring Boot properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the properties as

```
HS_TARGETS_0_NAME: system-a
HS_TARGETS_0_URL: https://system-a
HS_TARGETS_0_USERNAME: username_a
HS_TARGETS_0_PASSWORD: password_a
HS_TARGETS_1_NAME: system-b
HS_TARGETS_1_URL: https://system-b
HS_TARGETS_1_USERNAME: username_b
HS_TARGETS_1_PASSWORD: password_b
```

Tested with Spring Boot 2.1.17